# Generate unique ID based on data duplicity

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

So I've got a dataframe like so,

```
ID,SUBJECT_CODE,SUBJECT_GROUP,CLASS_ID,CAMPUS_ID
1,g1,VP2K,c1,r1
2,g1,VP2K,c1,r1
3,g1,VP3K,c2,r2
4,g1,VP3K,c2,r2
5,g1,VP3K,c3,r3
```

I have to maintain a column `CORR_ID` with values being a unique UUID (`uuid.uuid4().int`) for all unique rows and the same UUID for the duplicate rows. A row is considered to be duplicate if it has the same `CLASS_ID` and `CAMPUS_ID` (`subset=['CLASS_ID','CAMPUS_ID']`)

Expected result,

```
ID,SUBJECT_CODE,SUBJECT_GROUP,CLASS_ID,CAMPUS_ID,CORR_ID
1,g1,VP2K,c1,r1,142313746482664936587190810281013480411   //notice that the uuid of both 1st and 3rd rows are same, as both have same ['CLASS_ID','CAMPUS_ID']. Similarly for the 2nd and 4th rows.
2,g1,VP3K,c2,r2,342313743483664636887990810281013450392
3,g1,VP2K,c1,r1,142313746482664936587190810281013480411
4,g1,VP3K,c2,r2,342313743483664636887990810281013450392
5,g1,VP3K,c3,r3,247313743481654636887998810278015678903
```

So, I was wondering whether there was a pythonic way to go about doing this. Would appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me was problem save big integers to pandas column, because `OverflowError` error. Possible solution is convert values to `Decimal`:

```
from decimal import Decimal

f = lambda x: Decimal(uuid.uuid4().int)
df['CORR_ID'] = df.groupby(['CLASS_ID','CAMPUS_ID'])['CLASS_ID'].transform(f)
print (df)
   ID SUBJECT_CODE SUBJECT_GROUP CLASS_ID CAMPUS_ID  \
0   1           g1          VP2K       c1        r1   
1   2           g1          VP2K       c1        r1   
2   3           g1          VP3K       c2        r2   
3   4           g1          VP3K       c2        r2   
4   5           g1          VP3K       c3        r3   

                                   CORR_ID  
0  169638083186337734039542386251361973037  
1  169638083186337734039542386251361973037  
2  279310814212899708123352457215494669311  
3  279310814212899708123352457215494669311  
4  187655807105121612884740725825459107251
```